# Running multiple workbooks at once

Tags: excel, vba

How can I run multiple instances of Excel?

I have an Excel workbook VBA sub that does calculations at month level and it takes 60 minutes. I created a wrapper where you give it a start month and a number of months and it runs through it saving each monthly workbook.

The problem is there is a requirement to run it every couple of weeks temporarily with different background data that changes the calculation of the workbooks.  It is to run for 10 years monthly. 10*12*60 minutes. A lot of time to wait for workbooks that can run independently of each other. I only have 2 laptops with 8 cores each, seems a waste that Excel only uses one on each laptop.

The catch: the workbooks rely on the clipboard from time to time.

Comment: To clarify, by "multiple versions" do you mean "multiple instances"? I'd expect "multiple versions" to mean (e.g.) Excel 2013 and 2016 running simultaneously.

Comment: What has this got to do with the threadpool? It sounds like you need to run Excel is separate processes. How, then, is this about programming?

Comment: If it needs that long for processing the calculations then maybe Excel VBA (which is single threaded only) is the wrong tool. Consider switching to a real programming language and use the Excel sheet only as input/output for the data. • Pros: You can run as many instances as you want, and you can multi-thread. • Cons: You need to re-write your code for calculations and a interface for input/output to the sheet.

Comment: Instances fair call. The program is the program I just need to get it to work temporarily.

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest avoid using the clipboard (copy and paste) and rather use VBA objects. Then, to open multiple instances of Excel (to run multiple VBA macros), follow these steps: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-second-instance-ms-excel-new-window-64110.html

Comment: It could be the code that's taking the time to run.  Maybe it could be optimised - a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I agree with @DarrenBartrup-Cook. Could be an optimization problem, hard to say without code to review.

Answer (score 0):

I think PEH hit the nail on the head here.  Maybe Excel is not the right tool for the job.  In the Excel world, I've seen things start very simple, and grow unbelievably complex.  Often, things can be greatly simplified, and done thousands of times faster, simply by using R or Python.  Admittedly, it takes a little effort to make the switch, but it's totally worth it.  If you want to stick with Excel, and run multiple instances of Excel on the same machine, consider the 4 options listed below.

```
1. Alt + Open Excel

The first, and also my favorite method is the ALT + Open method. It works as follows:
Right click on the Excel icon in the taskbar. As the menu appears, hold down the ALT-key and left-click on the ‘Excel’ menu option.
New Instance Excel - Alt Open - 1.1

Hold down the ALT-key until the below window pops up. Press Yes to open a new instance.
New Instance Excel - Alt - Open - 1.2
Tip: you can also hold down the ALT-key, hoover your mouse over the Excel icon in the taskbar and click your scroll-button. This has the same effect and takes even less clicks.

2. Run Window

One of the quickest ways to open a new Excel Instance is using the Run window. To do this:

    Click Start -> enter ‘Run’ -> fill in “Excel.exe /x” and press enter.
    Or on Windows 10: enter “Excel.exe /x” in the start menu and press enter.

New Instance Excel - Start Window - 2.1

A new Excel instance will open.

3. Use VBA

This method makes use of VBA. Run below VBA code to open a second Excel instance. Do note, this method does not show a pop-up to indicate you opened a new instance.
Sub OpenNewExcelInstance()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub

4. Edit the Registry: Force Excel to Open in a New Instance by Default

This section explains how to open each Excel spreadsheet in a new instance by configuring a registry key. From all methods, this one involves the most steps to configure. However, if you need Excel to open a new instance by default, this method may be worth your while.
Note: this method only works when you use the Excel icon to open a new spreadsheet. When opening a new spreadsheet from within a file by using File -> Open, the file still opens in the current Excel instance. The same happens when you open a file from within the file explorer.
```